# Differences between various types of speech

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What are the differences between the following types of speech

**- Casual speech
 - Day-to-day speech
 - Informal
 - Street speech
 - colloquial
 - slang
 - idioms**

- Is casual = day-to-day? and is that = colloquial and slang all the
  time ?
- Is casual always informal or we could have a formal casual as well?
- Can I talk to my manager or in an official meeting in a casual way?
- Is informal always = colloquial or slang?
- Is colloquial and slang always = street speech
- Are idioms all formal or we could have informal idioms as well? and
  if so could these idioms be considered slang?
- Do we have two levels of formal idioms one used by book writers and
  another for used for day-to-day speech?

Comment: I would suggest that day-to-day, informal and colloquial speech all mean pretty much the same thing; the way people of all classes talk to each other in everyday situations (for instance, using contractions like _don't_). _Slang_ refers to very informal words used by particular groups of people. An _idiom_ is a combination of words that has come to have a particular meaning regardless of their individual meanings. Idioms are not limited to a particular register of speech.

Comment: What's about casual, is it formal or informal or both. Is it possible to talk in a casual way in formal meetings and at work or it is always an informal way of talking with friends and family members?

Comment: I didn't think it necessary to say that casual speech is, by [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/casual), informal. I would think that most people are able to have informal conversations with their co-workers - wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categories you name are often referred to as "speech [or language] registers"-- ways of speaking that conform to a particular occasion or social setting. You list a number of these-- but why these categories? That is, where did this list come from? Linguists and sociolinguists have spent lifetimes trying to define or to describe what constitutes such a list of registers. Surely a useful way to answer the guiding question would be to decide what terms belong on such a list, based on your need. But such a list could have 3 terms (formal, informal, slang) or it could have 20 terms, determined by (again) your purpose. For example, you could add "vernacular", and "conversational", and "jargon". . .and many others. I think the level of formality in spoken language should be connected to the level of familiarity with your correspondent-- you can talk quite casually, without editing every phrase, with someone you know well (even a co-worker), but with someone you don't know, your language would be more formal (such as in a meeting or a public setting). But it's important to note that such registers and levels of formality are different for the spoken and the written word.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Is it true that informal, casual, colloquial, and slang are more sort of spoken language compared to formal language which is both spoken and written and can be found in dictionaries? and does formal language refers to the common language used every day in pubic settings versus language used in literature and books? do we have such differentiation between formal and literature language?

Comment: As dmms says, formal language is used in meetings and other 'official' contexts. Most non-fiction books are written in formal language, though a 'how to' book might be written in in an informal register. Obviously, a story will probably contain dialogue which represents the way real people talk in informal situations.

Comment: My classroom example: no serious  journalist presents in street language. I'd call that dialect of English "public discourse":  when speaking to strangers, you should do so in Standard English. You talk to your BFF with a different diction and delivery. While expository prose is usu. written in S.E., since Hunter Thompson's "Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas" (1971) the rules have changed. Still, you wouldn't see an article in _Foreign Affairs_ that starts"Yo yo, what up homie, fightin' goin' over there." To me, a news reader trying to speak street (as I just did, rather badly) loses credibility.